# $A^{**}$ is isometric to $A''$

Tags: representation-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, universal-property

The  picture bellow can be found in  *$C^*$-ALGEBRAS 
AND THEIR 
AUTOMORPHISM 
GROUPS* by Pedersen.

[image]

In the picture, $S$ denotes all the states on the C* algebra, $(\pi_S ,H_S)$ denotes the universal representation of $A$ and $A''$ denotes $\pi_S(A)''$.

The proof is so short that I have several questions on it.

> Each state of $A$ is a vector state in $(\pi_S ,H_S)$ and therefore a normal state 
>   on $A''$.

I know that for each state $\tau\in S$, $\tau(a)= \langle \pi_\tau(a)x_\tau, x_\tau\rangle$, where $(\pi_\tau, H_\tau)$ is the GNS representation associated with $\tau$ and $x_\tau$ is the cyclic vector for the representation. So “the  normal state 
on $A''$” is $\tilde{\tau}:A''\to \mathbb{C}, u\mapsto \langle u x_\tau,x_\tau\rangle$? But I find nowhere to use the normalcy in the following.

> Since by Jordan Decomposition each element of $A^*$ is a linear combination of elements 
>   from $S$ we can therefore define a map from $A^*$ into $A''_*$.

For each state $\tau\in S$, $\tilde{\tau}$ is  weakly continuous, so it is $\sigma$-weakly continuous and the map $A^*\to A''_*, \sigma=\sum_{j=0}^3 k_j\tau_j\mapsto \sum_{j=0}^3 k_j\tilde{\tau_j}$ is well defined?

> As $A$ is $\sigma$-weakly dense in $A''$ this map will be a linear isometry.

Is  $A$  $\sigma$-weakly dense in $A''$? I only know that $A$ is weakly and  strongly dense in $A''$, and here $A$ needs to be unital.

And I think it is sufficient to use SOT to imply isometry.
Note that  $\tilde{\tau}$ is weakly continuous on $A''$, and the weak closure of the closed unit ball of $A$ is equal to the closed  unit ball of $A''$ by Kaplansky Density Theorem.

There's no need to answer all the questions, one of them is appreciated. Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I find nowhere to use the normalcy in the following.

If you don't have normalcy, you cannot think of $\tau$ as a normal state on $A''$, so you don't have the mapping $A^*\longmapsto (A'')_*$.

> I only know that A is weakly and strongly dense in A′′, and here A needs to be unital.

And that's enough (you don't even need to consider the particular representation here). The $\sigma$-weak topology agrees with the wot on bounded sets. So you have, using Kaplanski
$$
\overline{A_1}^{\sigma\text{-weak}}=\overline{A_1}^{wot}=\overline{A_1}^{sot}=(\overline{A}^{sot})_1=(A'')_1.
$$
So, given $x\in A''$, you have $x/\|x\|\in (A'')_1$, and by the above this is a $\sigma$-weak limit of elements of $A$. That is, $A$ is $\sigma$-weak dense in $A''$.

Comment: Why do I have no mapping $A^*\to (A'')_*$? $(A'')_*$ denotes all the normal states on $A''$? I remember it denotes all the $\sigma$-weakly continuous functionals.

Comment: Yes, exactly, the predual is the linear span of the normal states.

Comment: I know two facts: 1.For a vN algebra  $M$, the space of  all the $\sigma$-weakly continuous functionals is the predual of $M$. 2. a positive $\sigma$-weakly continuous functional is normal.     Is a normal functional also $\sigma$-weakly continuous?

Comment: Normality for a general functional makes no sense. But a state is $\sigma$-weak continuous if and only if it is normal.

Comment: Good! If so, the proof seems smooth. And I can also think $\tau$ as a $\sigma$-weakly continuous functional as $\tilde{\tau}$ defined in my question is weakly continuous, so the mapping $A^*\to (A'')_* $ is well defined too, right?

Comment: Yes. The result about normality is 3.6.4 in Pedersen's book.

Comment: Two points: 1. In order to prove the linear map $A^*\to (A'')_*$ is an isometry, what we  need is exactly $\overline{A_1}^{\sigma-weak}=(A'')_1$ other than $\overline{A}^{\sigma-weak}=A''$, right?   2.If $A$ is not unital, $\overline{A}^{sot}\neq A''$ how to deal with this case?

Comment: 1. Yes.  2. "Unital" is not relevant at all in the Double Commutant theorem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2372106/a-is-strongly-dense-in-its-double-commutant-a  But the proof of the Double Commutant Theorem in this page does use the condition “Unital”.

Comment: Yes, I had not paid attention to that. Most books do the Double Commutant theorem by requiring the algebra to be unital. But that's lazyness. The real condition that is needed is that the algebra acts in a non-degenerate way (because the double commutant will see the orthogonal of the image, while the sot closure won't). And this occurs naturally unless one in considering some unusual representations.